# How to make imageview constantly spin?

Tags: android, imageview

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      android:src="@drawable/zaid1"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I have an imageview in the middle of an activity, how would I make it so it rotates 360 degrees endlessly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to use `RotateAnimation`:

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
rotateAnimation.setDuration(500);
rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

findViewById(R.id.imageView1).startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

Answer (score 3):

Or the XML way.
Create "anim" folder in your res folder.
Create an xml file, name it whatever you want. You're going to define your animation here.

Inside xml file put:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="359"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="6000"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
```

Now you simply load animation:

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.your_xml_name);
```

and then start it:

```
findViewById(R.id.imageView1).startAnimation(rotation);
```